# Front brakes grabbing after rotors changed and resurfaced twice

Tags: brakes, ranger

I have had both the rotors and pads replaced on my 2008 Ford Ranger due to the front brakes grabbing really bad especially under heavy braking on the expressway.

It was fixed and then it happened again so I took my truck back and they resurfaced the rotors. It drove fine for about one month and now it is grabbing again really bad.

Any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: One trick that has worked in the past is to lightly bevel the front edge of the pads - can help with noise as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably go to a different mechanic, that guy is nothing more than a parts monkey, replacing components on your car and hoping the issue will magically fix itself.

There are two reasons your brakes will stick, seized brake hardware, or seized caliper piston(s) because of bad brake fluid.

I'll give you the worst case scenario first.

Caliper piston is cocked sideways, the piston bore will be beyond repair- Need New caliper

Caliper piston is stuck, but the bore has heavy corrosion and scoring - Need new caliper

Caliper piston is stuck, but has light to no corrosion or scoring - A rebuild kit will fix this if available, if no rebuild kit is available, you need new calipers

Caliper pistons are fine but, caliper slide pins are seized - New caliper Hardware will fix the problem.

What's the cheapest way out of this?

If your caliper is bad, you can go to the junkyard, get a caliper, rotors, and pads for next to nothing. Make sure rotors do not have a lip on the outside edge, make sure brake pads are thick and even, also make sure the rotors are worn evenly,as in there is now tapper to the inside or outside edge

Check to see if caliper head shields and seals are intact too.

If all credentials are A-Ok, grab them. And give them to a shop that will allow you to have them installed.

Answer (score 0):

There may be many reasons.

This can happen if the brake pad material gets hard, or loose caliper pins cause the caliper to be misaligned.

Even dirty brake fluid may be the reason.

Improper ventilation of the rotor due to usage of the other wheel.

Rotor turned over the limit (thickness below minimum)

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I will definitely bring this to the attention of the mechanic